# Chicken Scheme read-line taking too long

Tags: io, racket, chicken-scheme

Is there a fast way to read and tokenize a large corpus? I am trying to read a moderately large text file and compiled CHICKEN seems to just hang (I killed the process after about 2 mins) whereas, say, Racket performs acceptably (around 20 sec). Is there anything I can do to get the same performance on CHICKEN? This is the code I am using to read the file. All suggestions are welcome.

```
(define *corpus*
  (call-with-input-file "largeish_file.txt"
    (lambda (input-file)
      (let loop ([line (read-line input-file)]
                 [tokens '()])
        (if (eof-object? line)
            tokens
            (loop (read-line input-file)
                  (append tokens (string-split line))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running it with a larger initial heap:

`./prog -:hi100M`

The program does a lot of allocation, which means the heap needs to be resized a lot, which triggers a lot of major GCs (and those are expensive).

You can see the heap resizes happening when you enable debugging output:

`./prog -:d`

If you want to see the GC output, try:

`./prog -:g`

Comment: Tuning the other GC parameters could also be worthwhile (try -:? for help on the available runtime options; they're also [in the manual](https://wiki.call-cc.org/man/5/Using%20the%20compiler#runtime-options), BTW).

Answer (score 1):

In case you can afford to read the entire file into memory in one go, you could use something like the following code, which should be faster:

```lisp
(let loop ((lines (with-input-from-file "largeish_file.txt"
                    read-lines)))
  (if (null? lines)
      '()
      (append (string-split (car lines))
              (loop (cdr lines)))))
```

Here's some quick benchmark code:

```
(import (chicken io)
        (chicken string))

;; Warm-up
(with-input-from-file "largeish_file.txt" read-lines)

(time
 (with-output-to-file "a.out"
   (lambda ()
     (display
      (call-with-input-file "largeish_file.txt"
        (lambda (input-file)
          (let loop ([line (read-line input-file)]
                     [tokens '()])
            (if (eof-object? line)
                tokens
                (loop (read-line input-file)
                      (append tokens (string-split line)))))))))))

(time
 (with-output-to-file "b.out"
   (lambda ()
     (display
      (let loop ((lines (with-input-from-file "largeish_file.txt"
                          read-lines)))
        (if (null? lines)
            '()
            (append (string-split (car lines))
                    (loop (cdr lines)))))))))
```

And here are the results on my system:

```
$ csc bench.scm && ./bench
28.629s CPU time, 13.759s GC time (major), 68772/275 mutations (total/tracked), 4402/14196 GCs (major/minor), maximum live heap: 4.63 MiB
0.077s CPU time, 0.033s GC time (major), 68778/292 mutations (total/tracked), 10/356 GCs (major/minor), maximum live heap: 3.23 MiB
```

Just making sure we got the same result from both code snippets:

```
$ cmp a.out b.out && echo They contain the same data
They contain the same data
```

`largeish_file.txt` was generated by cat'ing a ~100KB syslog file until it got ~10000 lines (mentioning this so that you get an idea on the profile of the input file):

```
$ ls -l largeish_file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 mario mario 587340 Aug  2 11:55 largeish_file.txt

$ wc -l largeish_file.tx
5790 largeish_file.txt
```

The results I got using CHICKEN 5.2.0 on a Debian system.